# Problems with loading from LocalStorage with JS

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```
//Set Variables
var cookies = 0;
var cursors = 0;
var prestige = 0;
var cursorCookies = cursors * 0.1;
var save = {
    cookies: cookies,
    cursors: cursors,
    prestige: prestige
}

function loadgame(){
var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
 if (typeof savegame.cookies !== "undefined") cookies = savegame.cookies;
 if (typeof savegame.cursors !== "undefined") cursors = savegame.cursors;
 if (typeof savegame.prestige !== "undefined") prestige = savegame.prestige; 
}
onload(loadgame());

function round(value, decimals) {
  return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
}

function CookieClick(number)
{
  cookies = cookies + number;
  document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = round(cookies,2)
}
function buyCursor(){
    var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(cookies >= cursorCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
      cursors = cursors + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
      cursorCookies = cursors * 0.1;
        cookies = cookies - cursorCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
    }
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost;  //updates the cursor cost for the user
}




window.setInterval(function(){
CookieClick(cursorCookies); 
localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save)); 
document.getElementById('saveinfo').innerHTML = "Saved: " + Date();
}, 1000);
```

It's my first time working with javascript and localstorage so please bear with me, thanks :)

All that I am trying at the moment is to load 3 variables I am saving but something doesn't go right.
My Testsite: http://atz-exportforce320313.codeanyapp.com/

Thanks for any help !

Comment: _but something doesn't go right_ That's not a good description of your error

Comment: It just doesn't load. I can not really say WHERE there is a problem as the console doesn't give me any feedback... Sorry. That is why I linked my test here.

Comment: Console shows multiple errors on your test site directly after it loads.

Comment: You can try just accessing localStorage as an array, e.g. localStorage["myTest"] = "Testing"; console.log(localStorage["myTest"]); If that works then everything is OK with localStorage access and you have issues in your code.

Comment: I am guessing that you're wondering why localstorage is not loading values on page reload. This post might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860132/why-do-localstorage-entries-get-reset-when-i-refresh-the-page

Comment: @MarioMucalo I added a small console output. It seems that it only saves zeros into the localstorage?

Comment: @Sagar I tried to understand the post you mentioned but can't really relate that to my little noob script :/

Comment: @Exportforce - not sure what you mean. When you say "it only saves zeros..." what does? When? Did you try to debug your code to see if the value you want to save is zero before saving? Is your JSON stringifying working properly? You can check the localStorage by checking Chrome Dev Tools --> Application --> Storage --> LocalStorage --> your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i pointed out in facebook messenger:

if you access a variable inside the localStorage that has not been created yet, `.getItem()` will simply return `undefined`
if you pipe `undefined` through `JSON.parse()` it will just return `null` aswell.
to fix this you just have to check the response of `JSON.parse()` before trying to use it.

a quick example:

```
var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('save'));
if (savegame === null) {
    // initialize default values here or simply abort further execution
    return;

    // if cookies, cursors and prestige are global variables you can access them through window:
    var variables = ['cookies', 'cursors', 'prestige'];

    variables.forEach(function(name) {
        if (name in savegame) window[name] = savegame[name];
    });
}
```

now additionally you are trying to save the state through this line:
`localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));`
wich will not work since you are not writing your variables into `save`
you essentially have to add them together from your global variables first like:

```
var variables = ['cookies', 'cursors', 'prestige'];
variables.forEach(function(name) {
    save[name] = window[name];
});
localStorage.setItem('save', JSON.stringify(save));
```

PS:
in general i do not recommend defining your stuff inside the global scope

Answer (score 0):

Alright finally got to debug out your problem. The reason your code is not working properly is that at the start for first time, there is absolutely nothing inside your localstorage.

So you have to first check if the value retrieved from localstorage is blank or not.

Because of the problem here, your setinterval was not being called at all and thus there was no storage happening.

```
var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
 if (savegame !== null && typeof savegame.cookies !== "undefined") cookies = savegame.cookies;
 if (savegame !== null && typeof savegame.cursors !== "undefined") cursors = savegame.cursors;
 if (savegame !== null && typeof savegame.prestige !== "undefined") prestige = savegame.prestige; 
}
```

Also in case you have solved your first issue and still wondering why the loaded storage is showing all values 0, it's because you never update your *save* variable. Do that and you'll have your code working fine

Comment: Thanks ! Shouldn't _save_ be updated every tick line 47 ?

Comment: That's upto you. Personally i'd update save if there is any change. And same goes for updating my localstorage.

No use calling the same thing when it does nothing right?

Also please do mark the answer as correct if it has solved your problem